# How to Typecast Global Variable in C Language

Tags: c, pointers, variables, global-variables, global

I have a global variable in header file mem.h as:

```
extern int m_error;
```

I declare it in my mem.c file as:

```
#include "mem.h"
int m_error;
void *init_mem(int size){
    void *ptr = mmap(/*arguments*/); //returns address and stores it in ptr
    //here I want m_error to store address stored in ptr
}

void free_mem(){
    printf("free memory: "); //I want it to print address returned by mmap() in init_mem function through m_error variable.
}
```

I can only use ONE global variable that is m_error. 
Therefore, my approach is typecasting m_error to something which can let it store address stored in ptr.

Comment: Variables in C can't change their type.  What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Typecasting does not affect the type of a variable. It only tells the compiler to treat the content differently. Your `int m_error;` will always stay an `int` which is not necessarily able to hold an address even with using casts.

Comment: What is the *real* problem you need to solve? *Why* do you want to do all this? And how would this even work on a system where an "address" (a pointer) is 64 bits and `int` is only 32 bits?

Comment: Since you seem to be operating under an artificial constraint, I take this to be an academic exercise.  In that case, I think you've entirely missed the point.  I infer that `m_error` is to be used for a specific, defined purpose (its name suggests that that is to report on error conditions).  Your task, then, is to do the needed work without using file-scope variables for any other purpose.  For instance, your `init_mem()` function could convey a pointer to the allocated memory to the caller via its return value, which indeed its signature suggests it will do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I need to use address returned by mmap() used in init_mem function in other function free_mem().

Comment: So *return* the pointer, and pass it as an argument to `free_mem`?

Answer (score 0):

***int m_error*** can be used to hold an address by using:

```
m_error = (int)ptr;
```

But as other comments have suggested, you as the designer need to understand what that means and why it may work sometimes and may not work other times.  It all depends on what address range your platform is running on.

If you're not sure what the address range returned by ***mmap()*** is, then you'll need to provide protections in your program to take the appropriate actions if the address is outside the range of ***int***.

If I had another option, I would pass the value of the pointer to the ***free_mem()*** function in order to print the value of the address.

Comment: You're correct.  I had that backwards.  I will fix it.